# jQuery - check if class exists if no destroy a function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to destroy a function depending on existence of a CSS class.

I want to check for class `.active`, this class is toggled by clicking a button.
I tried using

`if(jQuery(#test).hasClass('.active')`

but it only work once, if I remove `.active` still this function is running whereas I want to destroy it after removal of `.active` class.

I also tried `.unbind()` but no use.

Please tell me how do I destroy this function totally after removal of `.active` class

```
    function destroy_no_active_class(){
         jQuery('#test.active').mouseover(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();e.preventDefault();
                jQuery(this).addClass('highlight');
            }).mouseout(function () {
                jQuery(this).removeClass('highlight');
            }).click(function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                show_data(this);
            });

        });
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming by 'destroy the function' you simply mean you want it to stop highlighting the element, you can simply check within the handler once it's triggered, and execute the logic conditionally. This is also more useful than unbinding the handler, since it will automatically work again if the element becomes 'active' again.

```
function destroy_no_active_class(){
    jQuery('#test').on('mouseover.mine mouseout.mine', function (e) {
            if ($(this).is(".active")) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery(this).toggleClass('highlight');
            }
        }).on('click.mine', function(e){
            if ($(this).is(".active")) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                show_data(this);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Within the handler, you could alternatively do

```
if (!$(this).is(".active")) {
    $(this).off('mouseover.mine mouseout.mine click.mine');
}
```

The downside here is that, if the element becomes active again, you have to rebind the handlers. (Note `$` is simply an alias for `jQuery`. If you have a naming conflict, just substitute `jQuery` for the `$` in the code above as you have been doing.)

Comment: One thing to watch out for when using [off with only event names](http://api.jquery.com/off/) is that all handlers will be removed: "all events of that type (both direct and delegated) are removed from the elements in the jQuery set".  That may be ok in your case, but something to be aware of.

Comment: Not sure - try it out and see :)  That is why I prefer to be explicit and pass the original function back to `off` (or use a namespace) as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: You can specify custom namespaces for your events

Comment: @user007 lol, yep, what dc5 said. See edited answer for example

Comment: @nbrooks & @dc5, Thanks for the help. `mouseover.mine mouseout.mine` are working, except `.click()`, can I turn click() to `.on()` ??

Comment: Ok @dc5, as you wish :-)

Answer (score 1):

.unbind() is the right way to remove event behaviors.

Your code has errors in it. Be careful about the selectors you're using, and whether they should have quotes around them.

```
if ($('#test').hasClass('active')) {
  $('#test').unbind().removeClass('active');
}
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, on/off are preferred over [bind/unbind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to remove your event handlers after you are done with them.

If that is the case, you will either need to

1. keep a reference to the handler function so you can pass it when you remove you event handlers
2. use [jQuery's event.namespace capability](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)

As of jQuery 1.7 on/off is the preferred method of adding event handlers:

```
function myhandler(e) {…}

$('#test').on('click', myhandler);
$('#test').off('click', myhandler);
```